# Convergence of a Sequence of Projection Matrices

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a sequence of growing matrices $A_n$, and $B_n$, both of the same size, and both rows and columns are growing at the same rate for each step $n$. Furthermore, we assume that there exists some decaying positive sequence $r_n$ such that

$$
\begin{align*}
\| A_n - B_n \| = O(r_n) = o(1)
\end{align*}
$$

where $\| \cdot \|$ is the matrix operator norm, $\|M\| = \sup_{\|v\|_2=1} \|Mv\|$ for some arbitrary matrix $M$ and appropriately sized vector $v$.

$\textbf{Question. }$ Suppose now that we assume the columns of both $A_n$ and $B_n$ are linearly independent, so that $A_n^TA_n$ and $B_n^T B_n$ are invertible. Furthermore, we define the projection matrices $P_{A_n} = A_n(A_n^TA_n)^{-1}A_n^T$ and $P_{B_n}= B_n(B_n^TB_n)^{-1}B_n^T$, and I want to look at the following quantity:

$$
\begin{align*}
\|P_{A_n}- P_{B_n}\|.
\end{align*}
$$

Is there anyway to characterise the rate of convergence in terms of $r_n$ without looking at the singular values of $A_n$, $B_n$ / eigenvalues of $A_n^TA_n$, $B_n^TB_n$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $ A_n=\frac1n\,\begin {bmatrix}I_n\\0_n\end {bmatrix} $, $ B_n=\frac1n\,\begin {bmatrix}I_n\\I_n\end {bmatrix} $. Then $\|A_n-B_n\|=1/n $, while
$$
P_{A_n}=\begin{bmatrix} I_n&0_n\\0_n&0_n\end {bmatrix}, \ \ \ P_{ B_n}=\frac12\,\begin {bmatrix} I_n& I_n\\ I_n& I_n\end {bmatrix}.
$$
So $\|P_{A_n}-P_{B_n}\|=1/2$ for all $ n $.